# Google sheets pivot table - Value by max date in year for each name

Tags: google-sheets, group-by, pivot-table

See example in [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GsztgSVfRiAVcGKFmbpnLZI7zPc2ylTdzhqAh4pkir0/edit?usp=drivesdk) and image below. Contains the original table, the pivot table and the expected table.

I have a table with three columns: Name, Date, and Value.
I want to take the last date in each year and sum the values by names.
In both years I want the sum to be 2.

The problem: I can't get the sum of Values for the max Date in a year grouped by Name.

[image]

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Sorry. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=LAMBDA(x, {QUERY(x, "select Col2,max(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"), 
  QUERY(x, "select sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 label sum(Col3)'GT'")})
 (SORTN(SORT({A2:A, YEAR(B2:B), C2:C, A2:A&YEAR(B2:B)}, B2:B, 0), 9^9, 2, 4, 1))
```

[image]